# Many to Many Relationship using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I've implemented Many-To-Many relationship and wonder if this is the optimal way for it. Since I do not have extensive EF Core experience I would love if someone with more experience could check it out.

Scenario:

- Many users
- Many organizations
- User can belong to multiple organizations
- Organization can hold multiple users

```
// Organization.cs
public class Organization
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<OrganizationUser> OrganizationUsers { get; set; }
}
```

```
// OrganizationUser.cs
public class OrganizationUser
{
    public Guid OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public Role Role { get; set; }
}

public enum Role
{
    Owner,
    Admin,
    User
}
```

```
// User.cs
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<OrganizationUser> OrganizationUsers { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual IEnumerable<UserOrganizationOutputDto> Organizations
    {
        get
        {
            return OrganizationUsers.Select(x => new UserOrganizationOutputDto
            {
                Id = x.OrganizationId.ToString(),
                Name = x.Organization.Name,
                Role = x.Role
            });
        }
    }
}
```

````
// Database Context code that is related
modelBuilder.Entity<Organization>()
    .HasMany<OrganizationUser>()
    .WithOne(x => x.Organization);
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany<OrganizationUser>()
    .WithOne(x => x.User);

modelBuilder.Entity<OrganizationUser>()
    .HasKey(x => new {x.OrganizationId, x.UserId});
modelBuilder.Entity<OrganizationUser>()
    .HasOne(x => x.User)
    .WithMany(x => x.OrganizationUsers)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
modelBuilder.Entity<OrganizationUser>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Organization)
    .WithMany(x => x.OrganizationUsers)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.OrganizationId);

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of pointers. You are mixing data notation and fluent mapping.

replace `NotMapped` attribute with `.Ignore` fluent mapping.

Also I think its cleaner to move each entity into its own mapping config class using `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>`

Dont mix DTO and entities like that. Best practice is to project your entities to DTOs.

Comment: Good point about `.Ignore`, will do that

Comment: You know, the reason I mix this DTO is that I need to get list of users and their respective role so this was the cleanest way I could imagine doing that.

Comment: I would project to a UserDto with a UserOrganizationOutputDto

Comment: x.Organization.Name forces you to use include otherwise you will get null reference error. with projection its not needed. Alot cleaner. Best practice too